# NEXT.js Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: node.js, next.js, fetch

Hi guys I've created fullstack app with NEXT.js, TypeScript, NODE.js and MongoDB. Generally this is decode\encode app with all functionality on Backend side. My backend side is already deployed on heroku. Front-end I still have on a localhost till I solve this problem. When I fetch all of my data from Backend, first I see error mesage, then data from Backend.

Here below error msg:
[image]

And here below my code:

```
import { ListProps } from "./List.props";
import styles from "./List.module.css";
import { P } from '../'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


export const List = ({ children, className, ...props }: ListProps): JSX.Element => {

    const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState<any[]>([]);


    useEffect(() => {

        const fetchData = async () => {
            await fetch(`https://node-test-mongo.herokuapp.com/api/blog`)

                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    setBlogs(data.blogs)
                })
        };

        fetchData();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [blogs]);

    return (
        <div

            className={styles.ul}
            {...props}
        >

            {blogs && blogs.map((blog, index) => (

                <ul key={blog._id}>
                    <li className={styles.li}>
                        <P className={styles.title} size='l'>{blog.title}</P>
                        <P size='l'>description={blog.text} </P>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
};
```

I suppose, that there could be something wrong with my data fetching, but I'm not sure.

Thank you in advance!:)

Comment: I've noticed on thing: if I delete [blogs] from useEffect, than error will disapear

Comment: You can't have `blogs` as dep of this effect because it's recursive, you depend on blogs and update them at the same effect and then this effect runs again, updates and etc. So if you check network devtool tab you will probably see many requests and at some point it fails

Comment: Can I provide my data f.e. via context? And than put state from context to List.jsx useEffect

Comment: Sure, you can use context. But I'm missing what it have to do with your question?